# Testcafe can't find tests wrapped in iterator

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, data-driven-tests

I have few expand elements in my FAQ page, so I want to test all of them. 
When writing my fixture and/or test in `foreach` section, terminal reflects an error 
`ERROR no test to run.` I don't understand why

I tried to wrap the only test in `foreach` and all fixture with the test, the result is the same.

```
fixture('check FAQ expand items').page(URL.local.faq)//.meta({ status: 'indev' })
  .beforeEach(async () => {await waitForReact();
  })
  .before(async t => {
  await waitForReact();
  await list();
  }).only;
faqItems.forEach( (element) => {
  test(`check that ${element.getReact(({key})=>key)} is present`, async t => {
    await t.expect(element.find('[expanded={true]]').exists).ok();
  });
});
```

I expect test cafe will run  `faqItems.length` quantity of tests into 'check FAQ expand items' fixture

I run tests with command `testcafe chrome faq.test.ts`

[screen shot of run test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93zaU.png)

UPD

```
let faqItems: Array<Selector> = [faq.item];
async function list() {
  const count =  await faq.item.count;
  console.log(`count = ${count}`)
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    await faqItems.push( await faq.item.nth(i));
    console.log(await faqItems[i].getReact(({key})=> key));
  }
}

fixture('check FAQ expand items').page(URL.local.faq)//.meta({ status: 'indev' })
  .beforeEach(async () => {
    await waitForReact();
    await list();
  })
faqItems.forEach((element)=>{
  test(`check that ${element.getReact(({key})=>key)} is present`, async t => {
    await t.expect(element.find('[expanded={true}]').exists).ok();
  });
})
```

[result pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKlD6.png)

Comment: At first glance I do not see any error here. Could you please provide an example to demonstrate the issue on my machine? Also, specify the command that you use to run TestCafe tests and your TestCafe version.

Comment: I updated topic, please check. Testcafe version is 1.2.0

Comment: As I see in your code, the `faqItems` variable is initialized as an empty array. So no tests are found. I do not see the full code of the `list` function and I do not know what it does. If you are filling the `faqItems` inside the `list` function of `beforeHook`, it's not the right place. The `faqItems` variable should be filled in a synchronous manner before the fixture is defined.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It looks like magic, if I initialize array with first element my method which fill out array works good. In the output I can see tha 1st element stores to array twice

Comment: I updated topic according your tip. I don't understand why it is not working in case empty initializing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that array initialized empty. I don't know why but into test array contains initialized data instead of generated in "BeforeAll". It seems like a testcafe bug, but maybe I am too junior to understand root cause.
 p.s. by the way it does not matter where is fixture inside/outside loop.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you pre-condition part of code is not part of `forEach` loop, and that can cause of you a trouble. I consider to move `faqItems.forEach()` above `fixture` like that

```
faqItems.forEach( (element) => {
   fixture('check FAQ expand items').page(URL.local.faq)//.meta({ status: 'indev' })
     .beforeEach(async () => {await waitForReact();
     })
     .before(async t => {
        await waitForReact();
        await list();
     }).only;

     test(`check that ${element.getReact(({key})=>key)} is present`, async t => {
        await t.expect(element.find('[expanded={true]]').exists).ok();
     });
   });
})
```

If in `fixture` you have some test which shouldn't run for each FAQ items, then move it to another fixture.

Second, i am not sure, that you can use `forEach` here, because `forEach` as a loop and as function for Arrays is not working with `async/await`. You can use `for...of` loop or standard `for` loop

Comment: Thank you for your response.
- I move fixture inside ```for``` loop and it is not working.
On official testcafe site I found example of ddt.

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/create-data-driven-tests.html

Comment: How did you run your test? With what command? Or, if you have TestRunner, can you provide TestRunner code?